# Running total with monthly reset

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table structure as below:

```
declare  @TestTable as table
(
    id int,
    somedate date,
    somevalue int
)

insert into @TestTable values
(1,     '01/Jan/09',   10000),
(2,     '08/Jan/09',   -100),
(3,     '02/Feb/09',   -200),
(4,     '14/Feb/09',   -200),
(5,     '20/Feb/09',   -400),
(6,     '02/Mar/09',   -300),
(7,     '03/Feb/10',   -400),
(8,     '04/Feb/10',   -300),
(9,     '03/Mar/10',   -400),
(10,    '04/Mar/10',   -300)
```

My code:

```
select id,
      FORMAT(somedate,'dd.MM.yyyy') as   somedate ,
       somevalue,
       sum(somevalue) over(order by somedate) as run_tot ,     
       sum(somevalue) over( partition by MONTH(somedate) order by somedate) as m_run_tot

from @TestTable
```

Required output:

```
somedate    somevalue   run_tot   m_run_tot   Required_output
01.01.2009  10000        10000       10000     10000
08.01.2009  -100          9900        9900     10000
02.02.2009  -200          9700       -200      9900     ----Prev month Running total
14.02.2009  -200          9500       -400      9900
20.02.2009  -400          9100       -800      9900     
02.03.2009  -300          8800       -300      9100    ---Prev month Running total
```

I need a to claculate running total with monthly reset (later I can use with Yearly reset)?

Comment: What is your MSSQL version?

Comment: ms server 2017...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend doing this using window functions -- for performance reasons:

```
select id, somedate, somevalue, run_tot, m_run_tot,
       coalesce(max(prev_m_run_tot) over (partition by year(somedate), month(somedate)),
                first_value(m_run_tot) over (order by somedate)
               ) as required_output
from (select id, somedate, somevalue,
             sum(somevalue) over (order by somedate) as run_tot ,     
             sum(somevalue) over (partition by year(somedate), month(somedate) order by somedate) as m_run_tot,
             (case when row_number() over (partition by year(somedate), month(somedate) order by somedate) = 1
                   then sum(somevalue) over (order by somedate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
              end) as prev_m_run_tot
      from TestTable
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06e469143ca9a804e3c45b070b8825ff) is a db<>fiddle.

The logic is to calculate the running total on the first date in each month and then spread that through the month.

Note that this also fixes the `partition by`s so they include the year as well as the month.

You could actually do this without subqueries by subtracting two cumulative sums:

```
select id, somedate, somevalue,
       sum(somevalue) over (order by somedate) as run_tot ,     
       sum(somevalue) over (partition by year(somedate), month(somedate) order by somedate) as m_run_tot,
       (case when rank() over (order by year(somedate), month(somedate)) = 1
             then first_value(somevalue) over (order by somedate)
             else sum(somevalue) over (order by somedate) - sum(somevalue) over (partition by year(somedate), month(somedate) order by somedate)
        end) as required_output
from TestTable;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c690a8f39ee4d33ee10eb3fa24b49b45) is the db<>fiddle for this version.

Comment: wow thanks  a lot... what need to change for yearly reset for window function..? as per @sb  in subquery i need to change 
B.somedate <= dateadd(DD,-(DATEPART(dayofyear,A.somedate)),A.somedate)

Comment: @Ajt . . . This version *does* do a yearly reset for each year, because partitioning by month alone doesn't make sense.  If this doesn't address your comment, you should ask a *new* question.  This answers the question that you have asked here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with CTE and SUB QUERY to achieve your desired output as below-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=66ad8a5aae17d11a9258cda52d73fc39)

```
WITh CTE AS
(
    select id,
    FORMAT(somedate,'dd.MM.yyyy') as   somedate ,
    somevalue,
    sum(somevalue) over(order by somedate) as run_tot ,     
    sum(somevalue) over( partition by MONTH(somedate) order by somedate) as m_run_tot
    ,
    (SELECT TOP 1 somevalue from @TestTable order by somedate) start_value
    ,
    (
        SELECT SUM(somevalue) 
        FROM @TestTable B 
        WHERE B.somedate <= dateadd(DD,-(DAY(A.somedate)),A.somedate)
    ) r_value
    from @TestTable A
)

SELECT somedate,somevalue,run_tot,
CASE 
    WHEN r_value IS NULL THEN start_value
    ELSE r_value
END m_run_tot
FROM CTE
```

Comment: dateadd(DD,-(DAY(A.somedate)),A.somedate) what need to changed if yearly reset?

Comment: you can check DATEPART(dayofyear,GETDATE())

Comment: @Ajt . . . Yes.  I've offered two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

heres my version without cte, without subquery..

```
declare  @TestTable as table
(
    id int,
    somedate date,
    somevalue int
)

insert into @TestTable values
(1,     '01/Jan/09',   10000),
(2,     '08/Jan/09',   -100),
(3,     '02/Feb/09',   -200),
(4,     '14/Feb/09',   -200),
(5,     '20/Feb/09',   -400),
(6,     '02/Mar/09',   -300)


select id,
      FORMAT(somedate,'dd.MM.yyyy') as   somedate ,
       somevalue,
       sum(somevalue) over( order by somedate) as run_tot ,     
       sum(somevalue) over( partition by MONTH(somedate) order by somedate) as m_run_tot,
       required_output= case 
                        when row_number() over (order by somedate)= 1 then somevalue
                        when dense_rank() over (order by MONTH(somedate))= 1 then sum(somevalue) over( partition by MONTH(somedate) order by somedate) - somevalue
                        else (sum(somevalue) over( order by somedate))-(sum(somevalue) over( partition by MONTH(somedate) order by somedate))
                        end
from @TestTable
```

Comment: thanks ...if jan  monshas 3 rows  solution will not work

Comment: @Serkan Ekşioğlu . . . This is close, but not quite correct.  You are subtracting out the value on the given date but in the wrong order.

Comment: @GordonLinoff its not that hard to fix.. is it?